# visual studio code window menu not listing open documents

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to get Visual Studio Code Mac to show open documents under the Window menu (like all other apps do)? It only lists the one document (out of all open documents) that I currently am editing in the active tab.

Answer (score 0):

MS says “as designed”...so that’s that.